# Change Ant Design Grid from 24 to 80 sections

Tags: css, grid, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using the **Ant Grid system**, It is based on 12 Grids System, and divided into 24 sections.

I need 80 sections is there any way to achieve it.
Here is the Grid

```
<Row>
  <Col span={24}>col</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col span={12}>col-12</Col>
  <Col span={12}>col-12</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col span={8}>col-8</Col>
  <Col span={8}>col-8</Col>
  <Col span={8}>col-8</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col span={6}>col-6</Col>
  <Col span={6}>col-6</Col>
  <Col span={6}>col-6</Col>
  <Col span={6}>col-6</Col>
</Row>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/47twd)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less, You should customize your `default.less` file:

```
// Grid system
@grid-columns: 24;
```